# linux sort not work correctly

Tags: linux, shell

I found cat not working correctly.

```
>cat bbb.txt
1343,10360
1193,10424
337,10222
306,10518
209,10410
1954,4861
190,10101
1811,6134
173,10555
1725,6542
97,9596
50,9996
20,5049
15,6007
10,6400
```

I want to sort it with column1, numberic, so

```
>_ sort -t","  -k1 -nr  bb.txt 
1343,10360
1193,10424
337,10222
306,10518
209,10410
1954,4861
190,10101
1811,6134
173,10555
1725,6542
97,9596
50,9996
20,5049
15,6007
10,6400
```

If I replace all ',' with ';' it works. Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
kent$  sort   -nrt',' -k1,1  file     
1954,4861
1811,6134
1725,6542
1343,10360
1193,10424
337,10222
306,10518
209,10410
190,10101
173,10555
97,9596
50,9996
20,5049
15,6007
10,6400
```

If you do `sort -k1`, it sort from field1 till the end of the line.

read the `KEYDEF` part of `man sort`

Comment: this works. and another question, why ';' works but ',' not

Comment: @dormi330 `1,200` = `1.2k`